# Why is my validation running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I'm creating objects that have attachments.  I'm faking fields by splitting a real field (probably the real source of my problems).  Separately, these work fine, but my validations appear to run before my controller logic does when I attach a file, and I end up getting an error that looks like this:

```
undefined method `match` for nil:Nil at line ...
```

Are the validations triggered by paperclip?  How can I turn it off, or make my own logic run before the validations run?

My model looks like this:

```
attr_accessible :zipcode
has_attached_file :attachment

#this is the line referred to by the error message
validates :zipcode, format: { with: /a_meaningful_regex_here/i}

def initialize
  zipcode = '-'
end
def set_zipcode(params={})
  zipcode = "#{params[:zipcode1]}-#{params[:zipcode2]}"
end
def zipcode1
  zipcode.split('-')[0]
end
def zipcode2
  zipcode.split('-')[1]
end
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <%= text_field_tag  :zipcode1,@foo.zipcode1%> - 
  <%= text_field_tag  :zipcode2,@foo.zipcode2%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
  @foo.set_zipcode(params)
  if @foo.save
    redirect_to @foo
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try to log something in your controller just to be sure it is not processed before the validation like it should be ? Are you sure the regex is written like it should ? If not, try `/\Aa_meaningful_regex_here\z/i` because it seems the problem comes from around here, if the problem was from the content of zipcode you wouldn't have a nil object because you initialize it with "-"... So I think it's more likely with the regex or the syntax around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
before_validation(:on => :zipcode) { set_zipcode }
```